# Azure Notification Hubs - multiple templates, how to identify the proper one?

Tags: templates, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I need to define 2 templates that are very similar, the only difference being the name of 2 json properties. I am using installations to register apps, and from what I see, when defining the templates, only the template name and the template body is set (the tags property is marked as obsolete). I am using the NotificationClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync to send the notification, and I see that the method accepts 2 parameters: the property placeholders for the template and tags.

How can I determine which template to send along with the notification? If I add the properties corresponding to each template, will it know automatically to which template to map them to? Or should the template name be specified in the tags array?

Comment: Howdy, which SDK at which version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs , latest version (4.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the template name should be specified as the tag which will target the correct template.  See the [Sending Localized Push Notifications in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-xplat-localized-apns-push-notification) which gives more information

Comment: So the template name should be specified together with the other tags? When registering a device using a deviceId, I also add the device Id as a tag, and specify a template for each platform. If I want to send a notification to a certain device, then I would have to specify in the tags array both the deviceId and the template name?